# How to enable the register button (which is greyed out) for new plug-ins in Sybase Central?

Tags: sybase-ase15, sybase-rs

I want to register the plug-in for Replication Manager in Sybase Central but the register button is greyed out for new plug-ins.
In Sybase Central's Help section; it says:

"The Register button is disabled if the .screpository600 file is read-only. On a multi-user operating system, the System Administrator is responsible for registering new plug-ins and you may not have permission to write to this file."

Any solutions?
Thanks in advance,

Ali